# Trying to get string outside LINQ .SelectMany statement

Tags: c#, linq, loops, razor

I got a solution where i need to make a calendar for artists on a festival. I found a way of sorting them with `.SelectMany().OrderBy().ThenBy().ThenBy()`

Now i need to get out of a loop `(ItemPublisher:Item.WhenAndWhere)` in LINQ to get the string `ItemPublisher:Item.Title`.

Any idea on how i can do this in the same LINQ statement.

```
@inherits Dynamicweb.Rendering.RazorTemplateBase <     
Dynamicweb.Rendering.RazorTemplateModel < Dynamicweb.Rendering.Template >>

@using System;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;

@{
    var lastDay = "";
    var currentDay = "";

    var lastVenue = "";
    var currentVenue = "";

    var items = GetLoop("ItemPublisher:Items.List")
    .SelectMany(item => item.GetLoop("ItemPublisher:Item.WhenAndWhere"))
    .OrderBy(item => item.GetDate("ItemPublisher:Item.WhenAndWhere.Date"))
    .ThenBy(item => item.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.WhenAndWhere.Where"))
    .ThenBy(item => item.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Title"))
    .Select(item => new{
    day = item.GetDate("ItemPublisher:Item.WhenAndWhere.Date").ToString("dddd"),
    where = item.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.WhenAndWhere.Where"),
    title = item.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Title")
    });

}

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__col-md-12 ">

      @foreach(var item in items) {

        var title = item.title;

        if(lastDay != item.day)
        {
            <h1 class="day u-margin-top--lg u-no-margin">@item.day</h1>
            lastDay = item.day;
        }
        if(lastVenue != item.where)
        {
            <h2 class="day u-no-margin">@item.where</h2>
            lastVenue = item.where;
        }

        <p>@item.title</p>

      }

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code has couple of issues:

1. `SelectMany` is to flatten data, so Select shall be integrated as part of the `SelectMany`
2. All kinds of Sorting shall always be the last operation, since that's for visual purpose, data selection and filtering shall be before sorting, only pagination shall be after sorting.
You shall have `Select` post `GetLoop` to flatten

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the code below.

```
@{
var lastDay = "";
var currentDay = "";

var lastVenue = "";
var currentVenue = "";

var items = GetLoop("ItemPublisher:Items.List")
.SelectMany(item => item.GetLoop("ItemPublisher:Item.WhenAndWhere")

.Select(artist => new{
    day = artist.GetDate("ItemPublisher:Item.WhenAndWhere.Date").ToString("dddd"),
    where = artist.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.WhenAndWhere.Where"),
    title = item.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Title")
}))

.OrderBy(item => item.day)
.ThenBy(item => item.where)
.ThenBy(item => item.title);

}
```